# How to express your agreement in German

Tags: meaning, translation

Having used various dictionaries, I came up with the following sentences to express my agreement with somebody in German:

> Ich pflichte ihm darin bei, dass die Zeit sehr schnell vergeht, wenn ich
> tue, was ich mag.
>
> Ich stimme mit ihm überein, dass die Zeit scheint sehr langsam zu vergehen wenn ich auf irgendjemanden warten muss.

I don't know if the sentences are correct or, if they are, sound natural or not.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is a bit odd. I d rather say: ich stimme ihm zu, dass die Zeit sehr schnell vergeht, wenn ich tue, was ich mag.

2nd almost correct, just a little change:
Ich stimme mit ihm überein, dass die Zeit sehr langsam zu vergehen scheint, wenn ich auf jemanden warten muss.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine, although "beipflichten" sounds a bit antiquated and may be unfamiliar to younger people.

You may also omit "darin" and say: "Ich pflichte ihm bei, dass ..."

Comment: Vielen Dank für Etklärung.